# Handling LangChain Async Calls

Tags: python, streamlit, langchain, py-langchain

I am using Streamlit to build a Chat Interface with LangChain in the background. I have problems to properly use the astream_log function from langchain to generate output. My app looks like follows:

```
├─ utils
│  ├─ __init.py__
│  └─ chat.py
├─ app.py
```

In the app.py I define the `st.chat_input` and call a function form chat.py to generate a response.

### Sequential code

This is the barebones of my app.py code when using sequential processing:

```
import streamlit as st
from utils.chat import generate_chat_response

# Initialize chat history
if "messages" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['messages'] = []

# Accept user input
if prompt := st.chat_input("Your message."):
    response = generate_chat_response(
        question=prompt,
        chat_history=st.session_state['messages']
    )
    st.write(response)
```

The chat.py file looks as follows (shortened to most important code). (My code is actually a custom chain with retrieval and different prompts)

```
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI

def create_chain():
    llm = ChatOpenAI()
    characteristics_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(
                """
            Tell me a joke about {subject}.
                """
    )
    llm_chain= LLMChain(
                llm=llm, prompt=characteristics_prompt, output_key="characteristics"
    )
    return llm_chain

def generate_chat_response(prompt,chat_history):
    chain = create_chain()
    response = chain.invoke({'subject' : prompt})
    return response
```

### Change to asynchronous

Now, I want to use `chain.astream_log` ([docs](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/schema/langchain.schema.runnable.base.Runnable.html#langchain.schema.runnable.base.Runnable.astream_log),[github](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/master/libs/langchain/langchain/schema/runnable/base.py#L402)) to access intermediate values in the chain (e.g. retrieved documents). Unfortuantely, the `chain.*_log` is only available as asynchronous version. The question is, how to change this code to make this work (i know I can't just swap out `chain.invoke` with `chain.astream_log`.

I already dug into many asynchronous tutorial but I can just can't seem to transfer the knowledge. I expect that I have to change from
`def generate_chat_response ...` to `async def generate_chat_response ...` and call asyncio.run() somewhere.

One difficulty for me is that there is not much documentation on the async part for langchain even though it seems to be a integral part of it. Paired this with only a superficial understanding of async is making me fail at this.

### Three questions:

1. is it possible at all incorporate the asynchronous function without changing the whole script to asynchronous?
2. What changes to my code do I have to do to make it work?
3. Is this even the best way to deal with this situation? I took this approach from [chat-langchain](https://github.com/langchain-ai/chat-langchain/blob/master/main.py) which uses fastapi to return the chat response.

I am kinda lost at this point and really hope someone can figure this out together with me.

P.S. please ignore that the code kinda pointless in the sense of being a good chatbot interface. For me it is most important that I can actually incorporate calling the `astream_log` to get a useful response.